# How to debug python code in VS code when there are multiple files that import classes from other files ? (Debugging when there are dependencies)

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, import

In all the youtube videos, people are just posting videos debugging with simple python file having no dependencies like imports. Can someone explain how to debug when there are multiple files from different submodules as dependencies for the current file we are debugging in VS Code ? I am facing import errors like "Cannot import blabla from blabla" when I was debugging. But normally if I run, it runs fine
I have even tried setting `launch.json` file Configuration to Module instead of current file.
Please help!
I am looking for an answer without using **ipdb**. Wanted to know using VS Code interface debugging.

Comment: Probably need a little more context in your question. Are you *stepping through* lines and receiving import errors?

Comment: It even did not give me a chance to step into, or over. It failed abruptly at the top lines of the import. ( I can see stepping through lines )

Comment: I added a checkpoint at. line#20, The import time, import pytest are in line #1 And they got executed successfully. BUT in line #2, there is an import ```from tests import bla```
There it is failing with "Cannot import bla from tests"

Comment: FWIW - Cannot reproduce with Spyder IDE.

Answer (score 0):

1. Based on the information you described, I created the following project structure:

   [image]

(In the file "`test.py`" of `b`, import the class "`class_aa`" in the "`main.py`" file of `c` of `a`.)

2. You could add the following statement at the beginning of the file "`test.py`" to add the modules that need to be imported to the system path to help VSCode find it:

> ```
> import os,sys 
> sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
> ```

3. Debug `test.py`:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate you have created a project structure to answer the question. 
I copy pasted your line 
```sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))```
at the top and still did not work. Seeing the same error "Cannot import bla from bla"

Comment: @Sumanth Vakacharla -Could you provide a more detailed description? For example, minimize the folder structure that reproduces the problem you describe, and the screenshot of the error so that we can view the relevant factors.(Please cover personal information when taking screenshots)